# Java - pass value of one radio button that selected to another frame

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

Is there any code that I can use to pass value of selected radio button to another frame?

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class bookBatman extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel jlbName, jlbTime, jlbPic, jlbDate, jlbDescription, jlbAuthor, jlbDateProduce, jlbDirector, jlbActor, jlbRate, jlbNoOfTicket, jlbPrice, jlbTotal;
    private JTextField jtfNoOfTicket;
    private JRadioButton jr1, jr2, jr3, jr4, jr5, jr6, jr7, jr8, jr9, jr10;
    private JButton jTotal, jBook, jCancel;

    Font f = new Font("Times",Font.BOLD,30);

    public bookBatman () {


        setLayout(null); //set LayoutManager

        // initialized the label
        jlbName = new JLabel ("Batman The Dark Knight");
        jlbTime = new JLabel ("Time :");
        jlbPrice = new JLabel ("RM 9.00");
        jlbPic = new JLabel ();
        jlbPic.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\OOP project\\img\\icon\\Batman.jpg"));
        jlbTotal = new JLabel (" Total : RM 9.00");



        // add all the label on the frame
        add(jlbName);
        add(jlbPic);
        add(jlbTime);
        add(jlbPrice);
        add(jlbTotal);


        // set all the label positions
        jlbName.setBounds(85, 78, 300, 18); //(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        jlbPic.setBounds(74, 101, 180, 288);
        jlbTime.setBounds(74, 400, 60, 18);
        jlbPrice.setBounds (270, 477, 60, 18);
        jlbTotal.setBounds (339, 475, 300, 22);


        // initialized the textfield
        jlbAuthor = new JLabel ("Directed by Christopher Nolan");
        jlbDateProduce = new JLabel ("Date : 17 July 2008");
        jlbDirector = new JLabel ("Author : Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan");
        jlbActor = new JLabel ("Main Actor : Christian Bale");
        jlbRate = new JLabel ("Movie Rate : 13 PG (Parental Guidance)");
        jlbNoOfTicket = new JLabel ("Number of Ticket :");


        // add all the textfield on the frame
        add(jlbAuthor);
        add(jlbDateProduce);
        add(jlbDirector);
        add(jlbActor);
        add(jlbRate);
        add(jlbNoOfTicket);


        // set the textfield position
        jlbAuthor.setBounds (273, 102, 300, 18);
        jlbDateProduce.setBounds (273, 132, 300, 18);
        jlbDirector.setBounds (273, 162, 300, 18);
        jlbActor.setBounds (273, 192, 300, 18);
        jlbRate.setBounds (273, 222, 300, 18);
        jlbNoOfTicket.setBounds (77, 478, 150, 18);


        // initialize the Radio Button
        jr1 = new JRadioButton ("11.40 AM");
        jr2 = new JRadioButton ("12.00 PM");
        jr3 = new JRadioButton ("1.40 PM");
        jr4 = new JRadioButton ("3.40 PM");
        jr5 = new JRadioButton ("5.40 PM");
        jr6 = new JRadioButton ("7.00 PM");
        jr7 = new JRadioButton ("9.00 PM");
        jr8 = new JRadioButton ("10.40 PM");
        jr9 = new JRadioButton ("11.40 PM");
        jr10 = new JRadioButton ("12.40 AM");


        // add all the radion button
        add(jr1);
        add(jr2);
        add(jr3);
        add(jr4);
        add(jr5);
        add(jr6);
        add(jr7);
        add(jr8);
        add(jr9);
        add(jr10);


        // set the radion button positions
        jr1.setBounds (75, 423, 100, 24);
        jr2.setBounds (172, 423, 100, 24);
        jr3.setBounds (269, 423, 100, 24);
        jr4.setBounds (366, 423, 100, 24);
        jr5.setBounds (463, 423, 100, 24);
        jr6.setBounds (75, 447, 100, 24);
        jr7.setBounds (172, 447, 100, 24);
        jr8.setBounds (269, 447, 100, 24);
        jr9.setBounds (366, 447, 100, 24);
        jr10.setBounds (463, 447, 100, 24);


        // group the button
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup ();
        group.add(jr1);
        group.add(jr2);
        group.add(jr3);
        group.add(jr4);
        group.add(jr5);
        group.add(jr6);
        group.add(jr7);
        group.add(jr8);
        group.add(jr9);
        group.add(jr10);

        jr1.setActionCommand("radio1"); // for ButtonGroup
        String sel = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();


        // initialize all the button
        jTotal = new JButton ("Total");
        jBook = new JButton ("Book Now");
        jCancel = new JButton ("Cancel");


        // add all the button
        add (jTotal);
        add (jBook);
        add (jCancel);


        // set the button positions
        jTotal.setBounds (191, 519, 83, 28);
        jBook.setBounds (285, 519, 93, 28);
        jCancel.setBounds (389, 519, 83, 28);


        // add actionlistener
        jTotal.addActionListener (this);
        jBook.addActionListener (this);
        jCancel.addActionListener (this);


        // initialize all text field
        jtfNoOfTicket = new JTextField (15);

        // add all the text field
        add (jtfNoOfTicket);


        // set the text field positions
        jtfNoOfTicket.setBounds (200, 477, 56, 22);
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if((e.getSource() == jTotal)) {

                    double price = 12.00;
                    double number = (Integer.parseInt(jtfNoOfTicket.getText().trim()));
                    double total = 0.0;
                    total = price * number;
                    jlbTotal.setText(" Total : RM" + total +"0");
                }

                if((e.getSource() == jBook)) {


                    String name = jlbName.getText ();
                    String date = jlbDateProduce.getText ();
                    String time = jr1.getText ();
                    int number = (Integer.parseInt(jtfNoOfTicket.getText().trim()));
                    String total = jlbTotal.getText ();
                    String price = jlbPrice.getText ();

                    //Passing
                    ticketReservation frame = new ticketReservation(name, date, time, price, total, String.valueOf(number));
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setTitle("Ticket Reservation"); //set title of the window
                    frame.setSize(800,600); //size of the window
                    frame.setVisible(true); //visible the window
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null); //center the window

                }

                if((e.getSource() == jCancel))  {

                    listOfMovies frame = new listOfMovies ();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setTitle("List of Movies"); //set title of thewindow
                    frame.setSize(800,600); //size of the window
                    frame.setVisible(true); //visible the window
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null); //center the window

                }
        }

        public static void main (String [] args) {

            bookBatman frame = new bookBatman ();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("Book Batman : The Dark Knight"); //set title of thewindow
            frame.setSize(800,600); //size of the window
            frame.setVisible(true); //visible the window
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null); //center the window

        }


}
```

Comment: Some random thoughts as I examine that uncompilable code.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).
An SSCCE of this nature, should not require images or 220 lines of code, of the 10 `JRadioButton`s, at most 2 (etc.).
Class names should be AllUpperCase.
It is better to use a `JFrame` instance, than extend one.
**Use layouts.**
Create & update Swing components on the EDT.

Comment: Please see (almost) SSCCE example below.  If anything is unclear, please ask.

Comment: crosspost: [java-forums: passing-value](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/42911-passing-value.html)

Comment: crosspost: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/361157

Comment: @HFOE: "Please see (almost) SSCCE example below."  Was that a design consideration to separate the Java files?  The first *could* be copy/pasted into the bottom of the second to make an SSCCE.

Answer (score 4):

Don't think of it as passing information from one GUI to another, but rather think of it in its most basic OOP form: as passing object state from one object to another. Often we use public accessor methods (i.e., "getter" methods) for this purpose and this can work here too.

Your ButtonGroup object will hold the ButtonModel of the selected JRadioButton (or null if none are selected) and so you can get the information from the model and return it from your getter method.

As an aside, your code has a lot of redundancies that can be reduced by using arrays and by using appropriate layout managers.

edit 1:
**For Example**
Say we create a JPanel that holds a bunch of JRadioButtons:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class RadioBtnDialogPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] BUTTON_TEXTS = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
   private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

   public RadioBtnDialogPanel() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));  // give JPanel a decent layout

      // create radio buttons, add to button group and to JPanel
      for (String buttonText : BUTTON_TEXTS) {
         JRadioButton radioBtn = new JRadioButton(buttonText);
         radioBtn.setActionCommand(buttonText); // set the actionCommand here
         buttonGroup.add(radioBtn);
         add(radioBtn);
      }
   }

   // getter or accessor method to get selected JRadioButton's actionCommand text
   public String getSelectedButtonText() {
      ButtonModel model = buttonGroup.getSelection();
      if (model == null) { // no radiobutton selected
         return "";
      } else {
         return model.getActionCommand();
      }
   }
}
```

We also give it a public getter method that queries the state of the ButtonGroup to find out which button model has been selected and then return its actionCommand, a String that holds the text that describes the radio button (here it's the same as the text of the radio button).

We can then show this JPanel in a JOptionPane in our main GUI and after the JOptionPane is done, query the object above by calling its getSelectedButtonText() method:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RadioButtonInfo extends JPanel {
   private RadioBtnDialogPanel radioBtnDlgPanel = new RadioBtnDialogPanel();
   private JTextField textfield = new JTextField(10);

   public RadioButtonInfo() {
      JButton getDayOfWeekBtn = new JButton("Get Day Of Week");
      getDayOfWeekBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getDayOfWeekActionPerformed();
         }
      });
      textfield.setFocusable(false);

      add(getDayOfWeekBtn);
      add(textfield);
   }

   private void getDayOfWeekActionPerformed() {
      // display a JOptionPane that holds the radioBtnDlgPanel
      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, radioBtnDlgPanel, "Select Day Of Week", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) { // if use presses "OK" get the selected radio button text
         // here we call the getter method  to get the selected button text
         String selectedButtonText = radioBtnDlgPanel.getSelectedButtonText();  
         textfield.setText(selectedButtonText); // and put it into a JTextField
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioButtonInfo");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new RadioButtonInfo());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good example of working _with_ the Swing [separable model architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/#separable).