# pass radiobutton value that selected to another class 

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

is there any example for me to pass radiobutton value that selected to another class?

```
jr1 = new JRadioButton ("11.40 AM");
    jr2 = new JRadioButton ("12.00 PM");
    jr3 = new JRadioButton ("1.40 PM");
    jr4 = new JRadioButton ("3.40 PM");
    jr5 = new JRadioButton ("5.40 PM");
    jr6 = new JRadioButton ("7.00 PM");
    jr7 = new JRadioButton ("9.00 PM");
    jr8 = new JRadioButton ("10.40 PM");
    jr9 = new JRadioButton ("11.40 PM");
    jr10 = new JRadioButton ("12.40 AM");

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup ();
    group.add(jr1);
    group.add(jr2);
    group.add(jr3);
    group.add(jr4);
    group.add(jr5);
    group.add(jr6);
    group.add(jr7);
    group.add(jr8);
    group.add(jr9);
    group.add(jr10);
```

im using this kind of way...right now i need to know how should i add for example; if i pick 12.00 pm... it will pass the value of 12.00 to another class...TQ

Comment: Hi TinyBelly, there are many examples, but in order to let us give you an example that fits what you are looking for, please be more specific, and show us some of your code if you have such.

Comment: Are you referring to the value (true/false)? Do you want to check whether a button is selected, and then pass the boolean to a method in another class?

Comment: @ TinyBelly what's wrong on example by `Hovercraft Full Of Eels` from yesterday, are you lazy to change WeekDays to Hours [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765010/java-pass-value-of-one-radio-button-that-selected-to-another-frame]

Comment: hmm...i still figure out the code...i dont understand since im new to Java...its take time to understand...i just need a simplest way

Comment: if you don't understand, then you ask specific questions in the original thread. You don't ignore the efforts of others and waste folks time by repeating the same question and by making many cross-posts without notifying all.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Swing Tutorial part on Buttons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) ...

Have the other class implement ActionListener and create this method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // do something
}
```

Make sure that on your Radio Button you call

```
radioButton.addActionListener(otherClass);
```

EDIT: To answer getting the text of the button in the question do this in actionPerformed
call getSource() on the ActionEvent and that will tell you which button fired the event. It is simply a matter of getting the text from the button (I think that is getText() but not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to pass the return value of `isSelected()` method to the object:

```
MyButtonWatcherClass watch = new MyButtonWatcherClass(); // not a real class, just an example
JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton("Simple Radio Button");
...
watch.processRadioButtonState(radioButton.isSelected()); // not a real method, just an example
```

Where to put this code is depended on you, but that's the main concept.

Watching your code, I can't resist - **use array**:

```
String hours[] = {"11.40 AM", "12.00 PM" .... };
JRadioButton jrb[] = new JRadioButton[hours.length];
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup ();
...
for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++)
{
    jrb[i] = new JRadioButton(hours[i]);
    group.add(jrb[i]);
}
```

Here, I said it :)

Comment: For me simply querying the button group works best.  See his duplicate thread on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765010/java-pass-value-of-one-radio-button-that-selected-to-another-frame