# Passing Radio Button Value From One Class to Another

Tags: java, swing, class, object, radio-button

I have a class that I've written that uses the console for user input. I am trying to create a GUI around it to enhance the program. As a result, I've created a new GUI class that i would like to use to pass values back to the existing class. I've spent hours scouring the forum and cant seem to find an answer the matches my specific problem.

The closest thing i found was [pass radiobutton value that selected to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769806/pass-radiobutton-value-that-selected-to-another-class)  and I've actually used the recommendation from that class. It seems to work "sometimes", though. What i mean is when i select the radio button "one" for the first time, nothing happens. I then click on the second radio button and nothing happens (as expected). When i click on the first radio button again, it then prints text to the console as expected. I cant figure out why it doesn't work on the first click. Secondly, each time i click on the seecond button and back on the first, it prints the expected output 2x more than the time before.

**/// Radio Button Class**

```
package views;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import common.ButtonTester;

public class RadioButtons extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnOne, rdbtnTwo;
    private ButtonGroup grp;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    RadioButtons frame = new RadioButtons();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public RadioButtons() {
        setTitle("Button Demo");


        initComponents();
        createEvents();
    }


    **/// Components**
    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        rdbtnOne = new JRadioButton("One");
        rdbtnTwo = new JRadioButton("Two");

        grp = new ButtonGroup();
        grp.add(rdbtnOne);
        grp.add(rdbtnTwo);

        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(126)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(rdbtnTwo)
                        .addComponent(rdbtnOne))
                    .addContainerGap(189, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(87)
                    .addComponent(rdbtnOne)
                    .addGap(48)
                    .addComponent(rdbtnTwo)
                    .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);

    }

    **/// Event handlers**
    private void createEvents() {
        rdbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rdbtnOne.addActionListener(new ButtonTester());
            }
        });
    }



}
```

**/// ButtonTester Class**

```
package common;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class ButtonTester implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello. I'm in the action Performed Method.");
    }

}
```

I expect that each time i click on radio button one, the sysout line executes once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void createEvents() {
    rdbtnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        // ****** A *****
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // ***** B ****
            rdbtnOne.addActionListener(new ButtonTester());
        }
    });
}
```

The line below (A) adds an ActionListener within an ActionListener, something that really makes no sense and is an unnecessary over-complication. This is why the first time you press the button, no visible output occurs as all that happens is that behind the scenes another ActionListener is added to the radio button at line (B). The 2nd time both listeners fire, the 3rd press, more listeners fire since you keep adding new listeners to the button.

The solution: simplify -- add a single listener to the button and add it once and only once:

```
private void createEvents() {
    rdbtnOne.addActionListener(new ButtonTester());
}
```